# how to Color map to dense optical flow

Tags: c#, emgucv, opticalflow

I'm trying to give certain colors to image based on their movement (like vector direction) in Emgu Cv. I have managed to calculate the dense optical flow to my video stream. I have used this

```
OpticalFlow.Farneback(prev,NextFrame,velx,vely,0.5,1,1,2,5,1.1,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.OPTICALFLOW_FARNEBACK_FLAG.FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN);
```

The variable vely and velx contains the velocity of vertical and horizontal directions.Does anyone know how to map colors to these. There are many algorithms that calculates the dense flow. HS also can be used, but I'm not sure what to use.
Any solution would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

[Optical Flow Color Map in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737580/optical-flow-color-map-in-opencv)

This is the same thing that i wanted, since I'm using Emgu cv I tried to convert this code to c# but I cannot understand how to pass the dense flow to function "colorflow".

```
public void colorflow(MCvMat imgColor)
  {
      MCvMat imgHsv = new MCvMat();
      double max_s = 0;
      double[] hsv_ptr = new double[3000];
      IntPtr[] color_ptr = new IntPtr[3000];
      int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
      double angle = 0;
      double h = 0, s = 0, v = 0;
      double deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;
      int x = 0, y = 0;

      for (y = 0; y < imgColor.rows; y++)
      {
          for (x = 0; x < imgColor.cols; x++)
          {
              PointF fxy = new PointF(y, x);                  
              deltaX = fxy.X;
              deltaY = fxy.Y;
              angle = Math.Atan2(deltaX, deltaY);

              if (angle < 0)
                  angle += 2 * Math.PI;

              hsv_ptr[3 * x] = angle * 180 / Math.PI;
              hsv_ptr[3 * x + 1] = Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
              hsv_ptr[3 * x + 2] = 0.9;

              if (hsv_ptr[3 * x + 1] > max_s)
                  max_s = hsv_ptr[3 * x + 1];
          }

      }
      for (y = 0; y < imgColor.rows; y++)
      {
          //hsv_ptr=imgHsv.ptr<float>(y);
          //color_ptr=imgColor.ptr<unsigned char>(y);



          for (x = 0; x < imgColor.cols; x++)
          {
              h = hsv_ptr[3 * x];
              s = hsv_ptr[3 * x + 1] / max_s;
              v = hsv_ptr[3 * x + 2];

              //hsv2rgb(h,s,v,r,g,b);
              Color c = ColorFromHSV(h, s, v);

              color_ptr[3 * x] = (IntPtr)c.B;
              color_ptr[3 * x + 1] = (IntPtr)c.G;
              color_ptr[3 * x + 2] = (IntPtr)c.R;
          }
      }


     drawLegendHSV(imgColor, 15, 25, 15);
  }
```

I having trouble how to covert the two commented lines in the code. Can anyone Help me with this.?

Another thing that the Farneback algorithm gives two  images velx and vely. It does not gives the flow( MCvMat). The colorFlow algorithms it takes the MCvMat type parameters.Did i done any wrong with the code. thanks